# SubclassDlgItem() debug assertion failed

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have created a dailog box with custom control. I am using ultimate grid in my application. (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20183/The-Ultimate-Grid-Home-Page).

I am having an error (Debug Assertion Failed) when I run my project.

```
BOOL CCustomControlDlg::OnInitDialog()
{   
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    // IDM_ABOUTBOX must be in the system command range.
    ASSERT((IDM_ABOUTBOX & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX);
    ASSERT(IDM_ABOUTBOX < 0xF000);

    CMenu* pSysMenu = GetSystemMenu(FALSE);
    if (pSysMenu != NULL)
    {
        BOOL bNameValid;
        CString strAboutMenu;
        bNameValid = strAboutMenu.LoadString(IDS_ABOUTBOX);
        ASSERT(bNameValid);
        if (!strAboutMenu.IsEmpty())
        {
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_SEPARATOR);
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_STRING, IDM_ABOUTBOX, strAboutMenu);
        }
    }

    // Set the icon for this dialog.  The framework does this automatically
    //  when the application's main window is not a dialog
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon

    // TODO: Add extra initialization here
    // Add "About..." menu item to system menu.
    m_grid.AttachGrid(this, IDC_CUSTOM1);//    ERROR LINE

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}

//Attach grid implementation
BOOL CUGCtrl::AttachGrid(CWnd * wnd,UINT ID){

    if( SubclassDlgItem(IDC_CUSTOM1,wnd))  // ERROR LINE
    {
        long style = GetWindowLong(m_hWnd,GWL_STYLE);
        style = style|WS_CLIPCHILDREN|WS_TABSTOP;
        SetWindowLong(m_hWnd,GWL_STYLE,style);

        // if the parent window is specified
        if(wnd!= NULL)
        {
            LOGFONT logFont;
            CFont *pTempFont = wnd->GetFont();
            pTempFont->GetLogFont( &logFont );

            // ceate a font object based on the font information retrieved from
            // parent window.  This font will be used as grid's default font.
            int nIndex = AddFont( logFont.lfHeight, logFont.lfWidth, logFont.lfEscapement,
                     logFont.lfOrientation, logFont.lfWeight, logFont.lfItalic,
                     logFont.lfUnderline, logFont.lfStrikeOut, logFont.lfCharSet,
                     logFont.lfOutPrecision, logFont.lfClipPrecision, 
                     logFont.lfQuality, logFont.lfPitchAndFamily, logFont.lfFaceName );

            SetDefFont( nIndex );

            // create a font that will be used for the heading cells.  This object
            // is almost identical to the grid's default font, except its weight
            // was increased by 200.
            nIndex = AddFont( logFont.lfHeight, logFont.lfWidth, logFont.lfEscapement,
                     logFont.lfOrientation, logFont.lfWeight + 200, logFont.lfItalic,
                     logFont.lfUnderline, logFont.lfStrikeOut, logFont.lfCharSet,
                     logFont.lfOutPrecision, logFont.lfClipPrecision, 
                     logFont.lfQuality, logFont.lfPitchAndFamily, logFont.lfFaceName );

            CUGCell cell;
            GetHeadingDefault( &cell );
            cell.SetFont( GetFont( nIndex ) );
            SetHeadingDefault( &cell );
        }

        CreateChildWindows();
        // When WS_EX_RTLREADING style was specified for the place holder
        // window, then set the grid to be in RTL layout mode.
        style = GetWindowLong( m_hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE );
        if ( style&WS_EX_RTLREADING )
            SetGridLayout( 1 );

        OnSetup();
        OnSheetSetup(0);

        // Allow drawing after the grid is initialized
        m_GI->m_paintMode = TRUE;
        // Adjust the grid's components to fit current setup
        AdjustComponentSizes();

        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

[image]

Anyone having any idea how to fix this??

```
// CAboutDlg dialog used for App About

class CAboutDlg : public CDialog
{
public:
    CAboutDlg();

// Dialog Data
#ifdef AFX_DESIGN_TIME
    enum { IDD = IDD_ABOUTBOX };
#endif

    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

// Implementation
protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

CAboutDlg::CAboutDlg() : CDialog(IDD_ABOUTBOX)
{
}

void CAboutDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

void CCustomControlDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    //{{AFX_DATA_MAP(CCustomControlDlg)
    // NOTE: the ClassWizard will add DDX and DDV calls here
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_CUSTOM1, m_drawpad);
    //}}AFX_DATA_MAP
}
```

Comment: *"Press Retry to debug the application"* - This will take you right to the debug assertion that failed, including the expression that was attempted to be verified. In this case it's probably, because you are attaching more than one C++ class to the same control (or attach it multiple times). Have you attached another C++ class to the control with ID `IDC_CUSTOM1`? Can we see your `DoDataExchange()` implementation and your dialog contructor?

Comment: class CAboutDlg : public CDialog
{
public:
 CAboutDlg();

// Dialog Data
#ifdef AFX_DESIGN_TIME
 enum { IDD = IDD_ABOUTBOX };
#endif

 protected:
 virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

// Implementation
protected:
 DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

Comment: void CAboutDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
 CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}
void CCustomControlDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
 CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
 //{{AFX_DATA_MAP(CCustomControlDlg)
 // NOTE: the ClassWizard will add DDX and DDV calls here
 DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_CUSTOM1, m_drawpad);
 //}}AFX_DATA_MAP
}

Comment: You should [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42275950/edit), and add the requested code.

Comment: you were right. there was a issue in DoDataExchange().

Comment: thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is, that you are attaching two different C++ objects to the same control (`IDC_CUSTOM1`). The entry in `DoDataExchange()` implicitly performs the subclassing by calling `DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_CUSTOM1, m_drawpad);`, while the code in `OnInitDialog()` is more explicit (`m_grid.AttachGrid(this, IDC_CUSTOM1);`), but essentially does the same thing.

To fix this, you have a number of options, depending on what you are after:

- Remove the `DDX_Control()` call in `DoDataExchange()` if you don't need the `m_drawpad` object attached to `IDC_CUSTOM1`.
- Remove the `m_grid.AttachGrid()` call inside `OnInitDialog()`, if you don't need the `m_grid` object attached to `IDC_CUSTOM1`.
- Add an additional control placeholder to your dialog resource and use that for either of those objects, in case you need both.